# Calculated field is not getting saved in database in django admin models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-admin

I recalculated field `total_amount` in `total_amount()` method. This working fine in django admin but updated value of `total_amount` is not getting saved in database column.

This is my models.py

```
class Orders(models.Model):
    order_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    order_item = models.ForeignKey('Product', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='order_item', blank=True, null=True,
        related_name='ordered_item')
    order_status = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    delivery_address = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    customer = models.ForeignKey('User', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='customer', blank=True, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    rate = models.ForeignKey('Product', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='rate', blank=True, null=True)
    total_amount = models.DecimalField(blank=True, null=True,decimal_places=2,max_digits=10)

    def total_amount(self):
        rate = Product.objects.get(pk=self.order_item.product_id)
        self.total_amount = rate.price * self.quantity
        return self.total_amount    

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'orders'
```

The value i got from `total_amount()` method is not updating in database.

this is my admin.py

```
class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ('order_id', 'order_item', 'order_status', 'delivery_address', 'customer',
        'quantity','unit_rate','total_amount')

    exclude = ['rate']

    readonly_fields = ('unit_rate','total_amount',)
    def unit_rate(self,obj):
        rate = Product.objects.get(pk=obj.order_item.product_id)
        return rate.price

admin.site.register(Orders,OrderAdmin)
```

Comment: The field will not be saved automatically. I think you should override the `save` method.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `total_amount` as model field, since it can be derived from other fields, also it's better to define `total_amount` as a `property` instead of a method.

```
# models.py
class Orders(models.Model):
    order_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    ...
    # total_amount = models.DecimalField(blank=True, null=True,decimal_places=2,max_digits=10)
   
    @property
    def total_amount(self):
        ...

# admin.py
list_display = (..., 'total_amount')
```

Comment: still not working ! now it is showing error ```Exception Value: can't set attribute```

Comment: @BadDub Have you made the migrations?

Comment: remove `self`, it will work.  `total_amount = rate.price * self.quantity; return total_amount`

Comment: yeah , i removed `self` and error is gone but its still not saving into database

Comment: @BadDub Yeah, As I mentioned before,  value can be dynamically calculated better not save to database.

Comment: cant we do by overriding `save` method

Comment: if you really want save `total_amount`, we can do this by using `signals` or override `save` mentioned below

Answer (score 0):

As @minglyu has mentioned in his answer, if you can calculate the total_amount, you should not save it as database field because it introduces data duplicity.

To answer the question - how to save - you need to override the model's save method like this:

```
class Orders(models.Model):
    order_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    order_item = models.ForeignKey('Product', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='order_item', blank=True, null=True,
        related_name='ordered_item')
    order_status = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    delivery_address = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    customer = models.ForeignKey('User', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='customer', blank=True, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    rate = models.ForeignKey('Product', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='rate', blank=True, null=True)
    total_amount = models.DecimalField(blank=True, null=True,decimal_places=2,max_digits=10)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        rate = Product.objects.get(pk=self.order_item.product_id)
        self.total_amount = rate.price * self.quantity
        super(Orders, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: `Exception Value: can't set attribute`

Comment: Have you commented out `total_amount` field ?

Comment: yes and it is showing `Exception Value:super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type`

Comment: That was a typo from my side. I've wrongly put `Product` instead of `Orders` in the last line. I've edited it. Can you check now?

Comment: now error is gone but still not updating in database.